# res.redirect not redirecting after a calling a function successfully

Tags: angularjs, express, meanjs

Hello I am new to express / angular.

I am trying to redirect to a page after a successful call to sendMail(). 
What is the the reason why res.send({redirect: '#!/testPage'}); isn't redirecting ?

```
           function (err, emailHTML) { 

            smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err) {
                if(err) {
                    res.status(400).send({
                        message: 'Failure sending email'
                    });
                }
                else {
                    res.redirect('#!/reviews')
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [express API](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.redirect) the correct syntax is: `res.redirect([status,] path)`

Comment: Thanks Michael, I tried res.redirect('#!/reviews') but still doesn't redirect me

Comment: which version do you use? express? nodejs? whatever else?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you made that request with $http, ajax request doesn't allow the browser to redirect, so what you are doing is correct. You are sending from the backend a json object to angular $http saying that should redirect to that path.
So now you need to make angular redirect to that route.

You can put window.location = result.redirect; inside the $http success function assuming that result is the variable with the $http response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return res.redirect(path)
```